# On what version of Java must I run Glassfish 4.1.2?

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-7

My understanding is that Java EE 7 runs on Glassfish 4. What version of Java must I use to run Glassfish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GlassFish 4.x requires Java 7 or Java 8. Java 7 is no longer supported, so Java 8 is recommended.

Page **1-3** of the GlassFish 4 release notes specifies the following:

> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition Release 4.1 requires Oracle JDK 7
>   Update 65 or later, or Oracle JDK 8 Update 20 or later.

https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/release-notes.pdf